# Pi Flashes Once and then Solid Red Light

Tags: pi-3

I have 2 Raspberry PI 3's, one boots the SD card fine and the other on power just flashes green once and then nothing happens but solid red light.

I've tried multiple SD cards formatted multiple times, and tried it on both PI's. It works on one pi but not the other.

Sometimes the PI will sit with both solid green and solid red lights and still nothing will happen.

After continued reboots and re-tries I now SOMETIMES get this weird screen to pop up but nothing after that.

[image]
Any suggestions/recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: what does one green followed by solid red mean? ... have you looked it up?

Comment: strange.., what os are you using? that screen kind of looks like the berryboot splash screen...

Comment: @scitronboy Just a standard noobs flash

Comment: isn't the noobs flash more bright and rainbowy? maybe you should try just running the raspbian image without noobs...

Answer (score 1):

Are any USB devices connected to the Pi? They may pulling the CPU power down below its minumum power during boot, preventing the device from starting. The red light would still be on, becuase that indicates stable 5V power from the micro usb plug, not to the CPU.

Otherwise, check the system OS: the boot screen shown dosen't look look like the NOOBS one; are you sure you're installing the NOOBS image? Sometimes unofficial ones cause issues with some Pis. Try just Raspbian, or a new download of NOOBS to make sure that you are downloading the correct OS.

If neither of these work, inspect the inside of the SD card slot of the Pi. If it is damaged, then this may be the problem. If there is no damage, then your Pi may be bricked. ):